# How to disable tags from printing in execution report?

Tags: ipaf, paceautomationframework

I am writing some test cases in PAF, my requirement is to disable some of the tags while executing and I don't want to print those in my report. How to disable tags from printing in execution report?

Answer (score 0):

User would be required to update the following entry in the **init.properties** file as part of the report configuration.

```
ignore.tags.in.report = tag name
```

(multiple tag names should be separated by comma) .